# Laravel - How to use rowspan inside foreach loop?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a problem to print rowspan inside a foreach loop. I want the result to look like this,
[Result that I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcRTO.png) (code with HTML)

I write my code in `php` file called,
**project-detail.blade.php**

```
<?php $no = 1; ?>
@foreach($tasks as $task)
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="{{ count($tasks) }}">{{ $no }}</td>
        <td rowspan="{{ count($tasks) }}">{{ $task->name }}</td>
        <td onclick="getTaskDescription('{{$task->task_id}}')">
            {{ $task->task_detail }}(Click for description)
        </td>
        <td>83%</td>
        <td>Not yet</td>
        <td rowspan="{{ count($tasks) }}">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" style="border-radius: 0"><i class="icon icon-plus" style="font-size: 12px">
            </i>&nbsp;Add Task</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Second task (Click for description)</td>
        <td>50%</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Review</button></td>
    </tr>
<?php $no++; ?>
@endforeach
```

However, I am not getting expected result. Result of my code looks like this,
[Result link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2CNS.png)

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code show correct view. Give some bottom padding on td . Hope you will be get your excepted view.